# Start a TeamCity build when a given keyword is detected inside checkin's comment

Tags: tfs, teamcity

I would to trigger a build if and only if inside the comment related to the check-in a given keyword appear (e.g: `{{start-a-build}}`). So for instance:

```
changeset 1: Initial Commit
changeset 2: Bug fixing
changeset 3: {{start-a-build}} First release
```

So at the first two checkins nothing happen. But as soon changeset 3 is detected, TC will read the changeset comment and since the `{{start-a-build}}` keyword a new build will be started.

Is this possible? Is this smart? What could be a better approach?

I use TeamCity 10.0.4.

Comment: _"What could be a better approach?"_ - that depends on _why_ you only want to start building after the third change. Are release branches what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. We currently branch by release. The question _"What could be a better approach?"_ is because I'm not really in ALM, and I know I have a lot to learn...

Comment: We can only answer that question when you explain why you don't want to build on every checked in change.

Comment: I would (for now) a simple release artifacts repository, rather than a full fledged ci process.

Answer (score 0):

TFS provides a default check-in policy named **Changeset comments policy**, this policy will require users to provide check-in comments. But there is no rule to require comments that include a specific text.

So you can create your own custom check-in policy to check whether the check-in comment include specific texts and call [TFS build API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build) to queue a build. Check out [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx) for an example of how to do this, as well as [this blog](http://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html).

Please notice, if your OS is 64-bit, you must add the checkin policy under the **Wow6432Node** instead of the path stated on MSDN:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\xx.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies
```

Comment: But I don't want to force dev to use *always* that keywords. They will use that keyword *just in case they want to start a Team City Build*...

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I mean you can create your own custom check-in policy to check whether the check-in comment include specific texts, if yes, call TFS build API to queue a build.